# forloop while loop integration

Tags: python, pygame

how can I make a for loop to repeat some sort of loop in itself?

this is the class:

```py
class Target(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,piture_path,pos_x,pos_y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(piture_path)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [pos_x,pos_y]
```

this is the block to create the random targets:

```py
target_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
for target in range(20):
    new_target = Target("target.png",   
    random.randrange(0,screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height))
    arget_group.add(new_target)
```

this block of code creates a set of targets to shoot, my goal is to If all the targets are down create a new set of targets creating a loop if possible.

ps. sorry new to pygame and python.

Comment: Can you give an example? It is not clear what you are asking. Basically, in the first iteration `target` will be `0`,  you can just use an `if`. Did you mean `new_target` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can nest as many for-loops as you want.

```py
for target in range(20):
    # some code
    for i in range(10):
        # other code
```

But I guess that's not what your aiming for.

> my goal is to If all the targets are down create a new set of targets creating a loop if possible.

So first of all you can remove a target with `target_group.remove(target)`. Calling `len(target_group)` returns the size of the group.

To check if all targets are destroyed you can use `if len(target_group) == 0:`

```py
target_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
for target in range(20):
    new_target = Target("target.png",   
    random.randrange(0,screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height))
    target_group.add(new_target)

# main loop of your game
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
    # check if a target should be removed
    # target_group.remove(target)

    # check if all targets are down
    if len(target_group) == 0:
        for target in range(20):
            new_target = Target("target.png",   
    random.randrange(0,screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height))
    target_group.add(new_target)
```

I hope I could help you.

PS: maybe you could learn form some Youtube tutorials on pygame. They can be really helpful especially as a begeinner. I'd suggest Tech With Tim (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-__8Xw9KTM) and DaFluffyPotato (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxRhvyZXd8I&list=PLX5fBCkxJmm3nAalPU6gGfRIFLlghRuYy). (I don't have enought reputation to comment, so I just added that to the post)

Comment: It's very unlikely that an instance of `Target` will be comparable to an `int` value.

Comment: That's the kind of thing you get clarification on *before* posting an answer.